# how to apply soft voting classifier for multi label classification

Tags: python, scikit-learn, voting

I applied 3 classifiers and I want to apply soft voting manually not by sklearn, in addition, I have 4 labels.

for example, I have 4 labels (L1, L2, L3, L4), each label has two classes(0/1):

```
class label:                      L1    L2    L3   L4

predict vlaues for classifier 1:  0.5   0.2  0.7  0.3
predict vlaues for classifier 2:  0.3   0.4  0.2  0.6
predict vlaues for classifier 3:  0.7   0.8  0.1  0.9
```

I want to apply soft voting manually (by equations) for multi-label, not for multi-class.
note: we assign equal weights to all classifiers: w1=1, w2=1, w3=1, and to make a decision for the classifier, if the value >=0.5 then the predicted label is 1 and if the value <0.5 then the predict label is 0.